# How can I correlate different types of variables?

Tags: correlation

first of all, my knowledge on this subject is very limited, therefore it may be a silly question.
I have 3 vectors, two of them are (distance vectors) in the range of 0 and 1, and the other is (Pearson Correlation Coefficients) between -1 and 1. I want to look at the correlation between them in Matlab, but I'm confused is it necessary to normalize the correlation coefficient?
If so I read that the correlation coefficient is not directly averaged. Does the same process apply when normalizing?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Correlation is scale invariant (at least for linear transformations), so the scale of the variables does not matter. More importantly why are you trying to measure the correlation between some distances and correlations? This sounds fishy.

Comment: Actually I measure similarity but in different ways. I just want to check if there is a relationship between them or not. Nothing special. It might be a silly idea.

Comment: It's almost always a good idea to plot your data before estimating a correlation coefficient, it might reveal something. You can add some plots into your question.

Comment: I plotted correlation heatmap without normalizing correlation coefficients. There seems to be a relationship between them, but the odds of me doing something silly and finding something good by chance. Unfortunately I cannot give more details on the subject.

Comment: Can you post these plots into your question?

Comment: Actually, I understand what you mean. The scale of the variables doesn't matter, so I don't need to use normalization. Measuring the correlation between some distance metrics (like Euclidean) and correlations (PCC) doesn't make much sense.